# Ubuntu is crashing after Java command

Tags: boot, kernel, java, battery, macbook

I have installed **Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS** on my **MacBook Pro** (2013). I have it installed nearly 2 years from now and until now there were almost no issues. But i hade to replace HHD to SSD and when i was taking apart my MacBook i found out battery was all swollen so I removed it and replaced disks. And problems had began.

1. **Java crash**: Yesterday i noticed that when I run for example minecraft server my Mac will reboot immediately. I'm running it with

   ```
   java -Xms128M -Xmx4069M -jar server.jar
   ```

   and it's nothing important, I guess, but I'm pasting this in here just to leave it all covered. I found nothing useful in the logs.
2. **Boot problem:** I couldn't boot it crashed and don't know even why because there was no log logging of boot that was unsuccessful. I fixed it somehow with `pci=noacpi` in the grub launch parameters.
3. **Fans problem**: 
   Fans are blowing on 100% without control. I think it's because I had to start MacBook with some weird procedure. They say also this:

   > When the MacBook Pro does boot, the fans will be blasting at full
   >   speed for the entire time you are using the Mac (resetting SMC or PRAM
   >   does not stop the fans running, only replacing the battery will).

   So I think that I can't fix it.

This is the error from syslog (`/var/log/syslog`):

> Sep 30 08:19:41 masmute kernel: [   40.153191] applesmc:
>   send_byte(0x04, 0x0300) fail: 0x00
>
> Sep 30 08:19:41 masmute kernel: [   40.153192] applesmc: #KEY: read
>   len fail
>
> Sep 30 08:19:41 masmute kernel: [   40.342196] applesmc: wait_read()
>   fail: 0x00

I want to fix mostly the Java issue, but if you can help me with the other problems, I would be grateful.

Comment: Any message about drivers in the boot logs? How did you replace the HDD by an SSD? Re-installed or copied HDD to SDD?

Comment: @xenoid I reinstalled whole system with latest Ubuntu 18.04.3 Bionic Beaver installer from their website using. Normal installed didn't worked i don't know why. I plugged in USB, it booted and i choosed install ubuntu server and it started to write those [  OK  ] ... you know what i mean and it just shutdown. I din't saw anything red it was going all so fast so don't even know what was going on. But i din't saw anything red. So i tried Bionic Beaver installer and it just worked all fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Fixed it by buying new server.**